# Modify first element in csv file python

Tags: python, csv

I need to manipulate the first element(which is an integer from 1 - 1000) of a csv file while also performing other operations.

Right now i have this code which prints a new row on every third row. But i also want to manipulate the first element with a counter on every third row by replacing the first element with a counter.

How my csv file after it is manipulated looks today:

```
1, information, info
2, info, info 
, , ,
3, info, info
```

How i want it to look after it is manipulated

```
1, info, info
2, info, info
, , ,
4, info, info
```

My code:

```
with open("mycsvfile.csv", 'r') as infile:
    readstream = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=',')
    with open("output.csv", 'wt') as output:
        outwriter = csv.writer(output, delimiter=',')
        i = 0
        #I want to manipulate the first element of the .csv-file here

        next(readstream) #to skip first row
        for row in readstream:
             outwriter.writerow(row)
             i += 1
         if i % 2 == 0:
             outwriter.writerow([])
```

Comment: Would you like us to guess how your `.csv` looks like ? ^^

Comment: @Dex' ter - I edited the post and explained some more. Didn't think it was necessary to show since i only wanted to manipulate the first element.

Comment: You said first, but your example modifies the second?

Comment: How can we reproduce your problem if you don't provide your `.csv` ? Maybe with my own example it works ^^ Instead of adding some more words, you could've just add a part of the csv

Comment: The csv-file contains exactly the same information as in the "after manipulated" example except that the only thing my code performs right now is that it writes another blank row on every third row.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the expected goal, but could you not just use `row[0] = i` just before `outwriter.writerow(row)`? I *think* you're working with a nested list so you can redefine items in that list by their index

Comment: @roganjosh - that was the type of answer i needed. Now i know how to perform my preferred operations. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I spent a good 10 mins trying to work out what you were trying to do from your example, so I have written it up as an answer to be able to close this question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting a nested list from the file you are reading. The items in the list are mutable, so you can modify items in them on each loop by using the index of the item you want to change:

```
for row in readstream:
    row[0] = i
    outwriter.writerow(row)
    i += 1
    if i % 2 == 0:
        outwriter.writerow([])
        i += 1
```

Comment: Put a `i += 1` after writing the blank row too.

Comment: @tdelaney this is the part I struggled with most. From the comments on OP, this was sufficient to close the question and give intended behaviour, I assumed the counter needed incrementing but not quite sure

Comment: @tdelaney looking back at the intended output after I unpicked it, you're correct. Edit made.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this qualifies as a full answer, but I'm not allowed to comment, so please move this to where appropriate:
You want to modify the first value inside your row, so what about something like:

```
if not i%3:
    row = modify(row[:1]) + row[1:] # where modify is some function that returns a list with a single modified value, i.e. modify = lambda x: [x.strip()] or something
    outwriter.writerow(row)
```

Comment: How do i declare the modify-variable?

Comment: It's just a function that can take in the value you want modified and do whatever to it: modify = lambda x: [x.strip()]. You don't actually need to define a function for that - do you just need to keep the first few characters? Oh and you need to make sure that your modify returns a list so you can perform the + op